# I need to show different inputs with every different choices and need to the others to remain hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to show a combo box and hide other inputs and show them only when I select one of the options.

I tried this, but they don't show at all when I select something.
Tried all the thing I saw online, but they didn't solve my problem at all, I don't know why;

```js
function showDiv() {
  getSelectValue = document.getElementById("hidden").value;
  if (getSelectValue == "1") {
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="select-styled">
  <option selected value="">Nessuna selezione</option>
  <option value="ds">Disposizioni semplici</option>
  <option value="dr">Disposizioni ripetizione</option>
  <option value="cs">Combinazoni semplici</option>
  <option value="cr">Combinazoni ripetizione</option>
  <option value="ps">Permutazioni semplici</option>
  <option value="pr">Permutazioni ripetizione</option>
  <option value="gs">Gestione stringa</option>
</select>
</div>
<br>
<div id="hidden" style="width:200px;" onchange="showDiv()">
  <label for="nTextField">Inserire n</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="textField" class="textField" id="nTextField"><br><br>
  <label for="kTextField">Inserire k</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="textField" class="textField" id="kTextField"><br><br>
  <label for="answerTextField">Ecco la risposta</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="textField" class="textField" id="answerTextField"><br><br>
  <input type="text" name="textField" class="stringManagement" id="stringManagement">
</div>
```

Comment: What is your _selection_ function from `onclick="selection()"`? And _onchange_ on div never fires.

Comment: Sorry, it still don't do anything ^^'' Im still working on it, Im not a good programmer, so i do things really slow

Comment: I didn't suggest anything, I just asked where the function _selection_ is, I don't see it in your post. And _showDiv_ is never called, _div_ doesn't fire _onchange_ event

Comment: the function selection() still need to be created and....I saw someone using it, maybe I saw it wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add **onchange** function on the select tag, not the div

```js
function showDiv() {
  var x = document.getElementById("select-styled").value;
  if(x != "") {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";

    // or any desired code...
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="select-styled" onchange="showDiv()">
    <option selected value="">Nessuna selezione</option>
    <option value="ds">Disposizioni semplici</option>
    <option value="dr">Disposizioni ripetizione</option>
    <option value="cs">Combinazoni semplici</option>
    <option value="cr">Combinazoni ripetizione</option>
    <option value="ps">Permutazioni semplici</option>
    <option value="pr">Permutazioni ripetizione</option>
    <option value="gs">Gestione stringa</option>
</select>
  <br>
  <div class="hidden" id="myDiv" style="width:200px; display:none">
      <label for="nTextField">Inserire n</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="textField" class="textField" id="nTextField" ><br><br>
      <label for="kTextField">Inserire k</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="textField" class="textField" id="kTextField" ><br><br>
      <label for="answerTextField">Ecco la risposta</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="textField" class="textField" id="answerTextField" ><br><br>
      <input type="text" name="textField" class="stringManagement" id="stringManagement">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="select-styled" onchange="showDiv()">
        <option selected value="">Nessuna selezione</option>
        <option value="ds">Disposizioni semplici</option>
        <option value="dr">Disposizioni ripetizione</option>
        <option value="cs">Combinazoni semplici</option>
        <option value="cr">Combinazoni ripetizione</option>
        <option value="ps">Permutazioni semplici</option>
        <option value="pr">Permutazioni ripetizione</option>
        <option value="gs">Gestione stringa</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <div id="hidden" style="width:200px; display:none" >
        <label for="nTextField">Inserire n</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="textField" class="textField" id="nTextField" ><br><br>
        <label for="kTextField">Inserire k</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="textField" class="textField" id="kTextField" ><br><br>
        <label for="answerTextField">Ecco la risposta</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="textField" class="textField" id="answerTextField" ><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="textField" class="stringManagement" id="stringManagement">
</div>

<script>
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";;
}
</script>
```